# How to calculate R,L,C on a bandpass filter?

Tags: filter, signal, analysis

As part of a project I'm doing for the class Signal and Systems Analysis, I'm given the following:

[image]

With A=10, T=0.25ms and To=1ms.

I am then asked to:

[image]

After reading a lot, I think that I should use the RLC Bandpass filter, but I'm not 100% sure. Also, the main problem is that I do not know how to calculate R, L, and C for the filter, knowing only the entrance signal x(t) and the frequency of the output.

Does anyone have any idea of how to solve this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes a band pass filter formed by a parallel L and C and fed via the resistor sounds the right approach but what you have to confirm is that the signal (1kHz square wave with 25% duty cycle) contains harmonic content at 3 kHz so, I'd advise you to do some Fourier analysis to confirm this.

Once you are happy that the original signal does contain 3kHz content then L and C are calculated like this: -

f = \$\dfrac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}\$.

The f term is frequency and in your case it is 3 kHz. This [web tool](http://www.stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RCL%20BPF/RCL%20BPF.html) might also prove useful: -

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. Really helped me and after doing some calculations and using the formula you provided, I was able to solve the problem and design the correct circuit.